# How to convert pandas columns to double in for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe called `df10`.

```
cols10 = list(df10.columns)
```

I want to change the data type to `double` where the column name starts with `"m_"`

```
for param in cols10:
    if param.startswith("m_"):
        df10[[param]] = df10[[param]].apply(pd.to_double)
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_double'
```

Answer (score 8):

the function `to_double` doesn't exist in pandas. pandas datatypes are essentially [numpy data types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html)

*i'm assuming you mean float64 by double*

you can either let numpy decide the precision for you

```
for col in cols10:
    if col.startswith('m_'):
        df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
```

or specify the precision yourself

```
for col in cols10:
    if col.startswith('m_'):
        df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float64) # or np.float32 or np.float16
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without loop,

```
reqd_cols = df10.columns[df10.columns.str.startswith('m_')]
df10[reqd_cols] = df10[reqd_cols].astype('float64')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `astype()` function to convert the column to `float` (python doesn't have a `double` type like C).

```
cols10 = [c for c in df10 if c.startswith("m_")]
df10.loc[:, cols10 ] = df10.loc[:, cols10].astype(float)
```

This approach is faster than using a `for` loop, but if you insist on looping over the columns:

```
cols10 = [c for c in df10 if c.startswith("m_")]
for param in cols10:
    df10[param] = df10[param].astype(float)
```

More on floating point numbers [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex):

> Floating point numbers are usually implemented using double in C